# Bookworm ate passport

Tags: visa, france, passport

Yes, this may be ridiculous as it sounds, but it happened.

I left my passport on my desk for about 2 months. The desk is small and not very dirty. But today when  I picked up the passport I noticed two small holes (with a radius of about one milimeter) that started in the last page. The two holes started from back to front just until the beginning of the visa pages, leaving the identification pages untouched.

I am Brazilian, and I am going to move to France by the end of July. I need to get an Visa and this takes about 2 months, and getting a new passport takes about a month. So this is a serious problem.

I am asking if there is a problem with these holes. I intend to apply for a visa with this passport, but I am afraid that this visa might get denied.

Here are some pictures for you to have a notion about the holes:

[image: Visa page. Hole in the left]

Visa page. Hole in the left

[image]

Holes in the back (last page)

My question is: Is this damage serious enough so that I am **forced** to get a new passport? I know it is obviously recommended to me to get a new one (I would do that) but the time is a serious resource in here.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would better if you apply for a new passport because of this.

Some border officials can be very picky about this.

It often possible to used a cancelled passport with a valid visa together with a valid passport.

I would apply for the passport, where possible  with proof of application.

When applying for the visa, inform them that a new passport has been applied for because of the damaged passport. They then may be willing to issue or transfer the visa to the new passport which may by then exist when the visa is issued.

If they know this beforhand (and the reason is obvious) it may be possible.

Comment: I applied for a new passport, but it is also worth mentioning that I explained the situation and they made my passport process much quickier. Thanks.